# Как вывести в textarea коды эмоджи вместо изображения

Tags: javascript, html, emoji

Из базы данных прилетает строка содержащая коды эмоджи. Когда вывожу эту строку в textarea то все смайлики преобразовываются в катринки. Как мне лучше сделать что бы они не преобразовывались а отображался именно код эмоджи?[image: Пример как не должно быть]

Comment: Экранировать данные соответствующим образом.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то преобразовать строчку можно так:

```js
const characters = '';

const codes = Array.from(characters, char => char.codePointAt(0)).join('\n');

console.log(codes);
```

Или, если вам нужно hex-представление, совместимое с JS литералами, можно так:

```js
const characters = '';

const codes = Array.from(characters, char => `\\u{${char.codePointAt(0).toString(16)}}`).join('\n');

console.log(codes);
```

Вариант с частичным преобразованием только эмодзи:

```js
const str = 'ab\n--\n**';

const strWithCodes = str.replace(
  /\p{Emoji_Presentation}/gu,
  char => `\\u{${char.codePointAt(0).toString(16)}}`
);

console.log(strWithCodes);
```

Comment: А если в строке еще присутствует текст?

Comment: Тогда перед преобразованием вам нужно проверить каждый символ. Например, превышает ли его CodePoint [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) или, ещё точнее, есть ли совпадение с эмодзи (можно использовать [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes))

Comment: Добавил в конец вариант с выборочным преобразованием.

Comment: Только я не гарантирую, что это будет работать со сложными эмодзи (с модификаторами). В этой области я не специалист, нужно разбираться подробнее, и там, кажется, есть ещё регулярки на подготовительных стадиях: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-sequence-properties